# check if linked server table column exists

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, linked-server

I have several access databases that I'm copying over to the sql server, connecting to as a linked server, and then pulling data from each night.

I need to be able to identify if the current access db the linked server is pointing too has a particular column.  If not I'll need to create the column before copying the next access db over.

Is it possible to check if an access column exists through a linked server connection?

Comment: linked server in the Access sense, or the SQL Server sense?

Comment: ^ I mean linked tables in Access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to make a connection first using VBA and then check with [sys.columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx)

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM sys.columns c
WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyTable') AND c.name = 'ExpectedCol'
```

Or use [COLUMNPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174968.aspx)

That is, check the metadata separately trying to query the column

Comment: I wasnt aware Access could have a linked server.  So it isnt possible for me to check using SQL I have to create a VB script to do this?

Comment: A linked server exists in SQL Server to connect to another data source. I assumed Access is talking to SQL Server via linked *tables*